# Toggle fa-thumbs-up icon (or any font-awesome icon) color on click

Tags: css, angularjs, font-awesome

I have multiple thumbs-up icons of font-awesome library on the screen. I want to toggle the color of the icon which is clicked.

How it can be done in AngularJS?

```css
.liked{
  color:#0000ff;
}

.not-liked{
  color:#888;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="">
<a href="#" ng-click="" class="not-liked">
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

Sorry, I have not written the AngularJS part (click method) because I am not aware with the Angular approach (though I have achieved it with jQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use **ng-click** and **ng-class** directives.

```css
.liked{
  color:#0000ff;
}

.not-liked{
  color:#888;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="">
<a href="#" ng-class="{'not-liked':!liked,'liked':liked}" ng-click="liked=!liked">
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

**Edit:** removed extra ng-click.

Comment: Thanks @Fatih for your response. Sorry to say but It's not working. Neither for single icon nor for multiple. It would be great if you provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks! but not working for multiple icons. If I click on one icon, others are also getting highlighted. Check here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpGZwx

Comment: You should keep track of each icon with a unique model(variable). So instead of using 'liked' model you should use 'liked1', 'liked2', etc.

Comment: Thanks! I ll definitely try it and will get back here.